# Processing the attributes and split them based on string

Tags: xslt

I need to take the attribute of "a" tag and process them.

Source:

```
<Data>
    <AAA>
    <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some Text
     <a href="#" name="Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6" id="Functionaldata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Value6</a>
    </strong>
    hello
    <a title="google" href="http://google.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hey</a> all <a href="#" name="element1,element2,element3,element4,element5,element6" id="Functionaldata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">element6</a>
    <AAA>
</Data>
```

Output

```
<Content>
  <Information>
    <text>
        <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some Text
        <dynamicinfo type="Value1" name="Value2" group="Value3" id="Value4" link="Value5" display="Value6"/>
    </strong>
    hello<a title="google" href="http://google.com">Hey</a> all 
    <dynamicinfo type="element1" name="element2" group="element3" id="element4" link="element5" display="element6"/>
    </text>
  </Information>
 </Content>
```

I am struck at processing "a" tags with id=Functionaldata.

Can any help their views on it.

Thank you.

Comment: User 222: Was my answer useful to you and do you still have any problems?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. It is useful to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:my="my:my">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <my:names>
      <n>type</n>
      <n>name</n>
      <n>group</n>
      <n>id</n>
      <n>link</n>
      <n>display</n>
     </my:names>

     <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="document('')/*/my:names/*"/>

         <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
             <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
             </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="a[@name] | x:a[@name]">
          <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='name')]"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
          </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="a/@name | x:a/@name" name="split">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
      <xsl:param name="pOrd" select="1"/>

      <xsl:if test="$pText">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$vNames[position()=$pOrd]}">
          <xsl:value-of select=
            "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:call-template name="split">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pOrd" select="$pOrd+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
        <AAA>
        <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some Text
         <a href="#" name="Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6" id="Functionaldata">Value6</a>
        </strong>
        hello
        <a title="google" href="http://google.com">Hey</a> all
        <a href="#" name="element1,element2,element3,element4,element5,element6" id="Functionaldata">element6</a>
        </AAA>
</Data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Data>
   <AAA>
      <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some Text
         <a href="#" id="Value4" type="Value1" name="Value2" group="Value3" link="Value5" display="Value6"/>
      </strong>
        hello
        <a title="google" href="http://google.com">Hey</a> all
        <a href="#" id="element4" type="element1" name="element2" group="element3" link="element5" display="element6"/>
   </AAA>
</Data>
```

**Explanation**:

This builds upon the solution of your previous question, with the following changes:

1. Use and overrides of the identity rule.
2. Instead of elements, attributes are created that have as value the results of the split.
3. The names of the attributes to be generated are specified as children of a global `my:names` element.

**UPDATE**:

In a comment the OP has modified his question, saying:

> I forgot to add the name space for "a" tag. All the "a" tags have
>   "xhtml" namespace.

The answer is that in this case the provided transformation works still OK, and no change in it is required.

However, it *could* be simplified in the following way:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:template match="a[@name] | x:a[@name]">
```

**with just**:

```
<xsl:template match="x:a[@name]">
```

**and replace**:

```
<xsl:template match="a/@name | x:a/@name" name="split">
```

**with just**:

```
<xsl:template match="x:a/@name" name="split">
```

**The complete transformation after these changes becomes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:my="my:my">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <my:names>
      <n>type</n>
      <n>name</n>
      <n>group</n>
      <n>id</n>
      <n>link</n>
      <n>display</n>
     </my:names>

     <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="document('')/*/my:names/*"/>

         <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
             <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
             </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="x:a[@name]">
          <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='name')]"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
          </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="x:a/@name" name="split">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
      <xsl:param name="pOrd" select="1"/>

      <xsl:if test="$pText">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$vNames[position()=$pOrd]}">
          <xsl:value-of select=
            "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:call-template name="split">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pOrd" select="$pOrd+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A small doubt, I forgot to add the name space for "a" tag. All the "a" tags have "xhtml" namespace. Then will there be any change in code.

Comment: @User222: If all `a` elements belong to the xhtml namespace, the transformation doesn't need to be changed. It *can* be simplified, so that the match pattern `a/@name | x:a/@name` becomes just `x:a/@name`. Please, edit the question so that all `a` elements in your source XML document are really in the xhtml namespace so that readers will not be confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to EXSLT you can use the `str:split()` method to achieve this.

The bigger question is, how are you mapping the values to the new attribute names you've given them? I came up with this, which declares the value names upfront and then maps value name 1 to split value 1, value name 2 to split value 2, etc.

```
<!-- node-set of value names, which will each correspond to the value at the same index, once they're split -->
<xsl:variable name='value_names' select='str:split("type|name|group|id|link|display", "|")' />

<!-- match root -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <dynamicdata>
        <xsl:apply-templates name='values' select='str:split(root/a/@name, ",")' />
    </dynamicdata>
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - each value from the split -->
<xsl:template match='token'>
    <xsl:variable name='pos' select='position()' />
    <xsl:attribute name='{$value_names[$pos]}'><xsl:value-of select='.' /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You can see this in action at [this XMLPlayground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/yfDT0d) (see output source).